# Gmail only first and last mails are good , middle ones ui are breaking

Tags: email, gmail

I was working on a project where i need to trigger the mails to client.
But when client recieves more than 2 mails only the first and last mails table ui are good , but the middles similar mails ui get distorted ( more specifically the table get removed only the inner data remains ) .

[image]

Below one is middles mails:

[image]
Note :
Intially for the first time all mails are good but when open again the gmail they broke.